# New Gaming System - GPU [Romania]

Tags: graphics-cards

I'm building a system to play the latest games at max settings at 1920x1080 and get as close to 30 FPS as possible within the budget.

The trouble is that the website I'm buying from is in Romanian, so using it depends on how patient you are with a few translations.

**Location:** Romania, Bucharest

**Site of choice:** dc-shop.ro ("Componente & Monitoare" from the homepage) / **EDIT:** Also using emag.ro (top-left "Oferta Produse" -> "PC, Periferice & Software")

---Part requirements--------

**Price limit:** 1500 RON (possible 1700 if needed to meet performance requirements)

**SLI/Crossfire:** No

**Monitors:** 1 x 24" with VGA (+DVI adapter)

**Connectors/length/noise:** not an issue/will adapt other parts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Gaming System - CPU \[Romania\]](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/new-gaming-system-cpu-romania)

Comment: @cyber I don't see how, when each of these is asking for a different component.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the 4 GB Sapphire Nitro R9 380, currently [1000 RON with free shipping at Emag.ro](http://www.emag.ro/placa-video-sapphire-radeon-r9-380-nitro-4gb-gddr5-256-bit-11242-13-20g/pd/D6RTZYBBM/). The [R9 380 is able](http://www.kitguru.net/components/graphic-cards/luke-hill/sapphire-r9-380-nitro-4gb-review/all/1/) to [average around 30 FPS on most modern games at 1080p maximum settings](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/amd-radeon-r9-390x-r9-380-r7-370,4178-6.html).

The Sapphire Nitro is the highest end line of Sapphire GPUs and are made with high quality components. It has a 5+1 phase VRM and good cooling, so you should be able to [overclock it a fair bit as well](http://www.eteknix.com/sapphire-nitro-r9-380-4gb-graphics-card-review/13/). 4 GB of VRAM can store larger textures and could come in handy for modern games. Unfortunately, the card does not come with native VGA, so you'll have to use your adaptor.

Another option would be a GTX 960, such as the 4 GB Gigabyte Windforce 2X, [1024 RON at dc-shop.ro](http://www.dc-shop.ro/placi-video/placa-video-gigabyte-geforce-gtx-960-oc-rev.-1.0-4gb-ddr5-128bit-l/). The two cards trade blows, and the only reason I've recommended the Nitro R9 380 is because it was a top-of-the-line model on sale right now for fairly cheap. You'd probably be able to overclock more with the GTX 960, and the lower power consumption will save money in the long run, but really, it's up to personal preference. The 960 doesn't have a VGA port either.

If you really wanted to play at max settings at 1080p though, consider spending a bit more and get a R9 390, such as the 8 GB Sapphire Nitro Tri-X, [1569.99 RON at Emag.ro](http://www.emag.ro/placa-video-sapphire-radeon-r9-390-nitro-tri-x-8gb-gddr5-512-bit-11244-01-20g/pd/DW55XYBBM/). It would easily handle any current game on your monitor, even with the eye candy right up. Even if you decided to get 2 more monitors to play triple monitor (exactly between the number of pixels of QHD (2x) and UHD (4x)), it [would still meet your FPS requirements with ease.](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/sapphire-nitro-r9-390-8g-d5,4245.html) Be warned though, this card can draw almost 350 W of power! If you don't want or need a GPU this powerful, I suggest you recycle some of your budget. An extra 100 for the CPU and 300 for the SSD should get you some better options.