# New Gaming System - CPU [Romania]

Tags: processor

I'm building a system to play the latest games at max settings at 1920x1080 and get as close to 30 FPS as possible within the budget.

The trouble is that the website I'm buying from is in Romanian, so using it depends on how patient you are with a few translations.

**Location:** Romania, Bucharest

**Site of choice:** dc-shop.ro ("Componente & Monitoare" from the homepage) / **EDIT:** Also using emag.ro (top-left "Oferta Produse" -> "PC, Periferice & Software")

---Part requirements--------

**Price limit:** 800 RON

**Architecture:** Intel Skylake

**Overclocking:** No

**Noise (heatsink fan):** not an issue

Comment: It's going to be tough to get a system running that can play the "latest games at max settings" with your budget. Just a video card from last generation is going to put you through your budget. Do you have a case, motherboard, RAM, HDD, PSU and CPU already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Gaming System - Case \[Romania\]](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/new-gaming-system-case-romania)

Comment: @NZKshatriya I don't see how the two are duplicates when they ask about completely different components.

Comment: My bad, the question duplicates itself for the most part, ending with changes.....no more browsing at 2am.