# New Gaming System - Case [Romania]

Tags: case

I'm building a system to play the latest games at max settings at 1920x1080 and get as close to 30 FPS as possible within the budget.

The trouble is that the website I'm buying from is in Romanian, so using it depends on how patient you are with a few translations.

**Location:** Romania, Bucharest

**Site of choice:** dc-shop.ro ("Componente & Monitoare" from the homepage) / **EDIT:** Also using emag.ro (top-left "Oferta Produse" -> "PC, Periferice & Software")

---Part requirements--------

**Price limit:** 700
RON

**Format:** ATX

**Color:** Black/Dark grey

**Design:** Simple, no LEDs, no side panels

**Internal:** Should fit the largest GPU (newest models) & as screwless as possible

**Cooling:** Air cooled, min 2 front fans & 1 back fan as large as possible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because build requests are off-topic

Comment: @NZKshatriya IIRC Build requests for specific components are on topic, provided that they aren't too broad (which this question might be in danger of being)