# New Gaming System - SSD [Romania]

Tags: ssd

I'm building a system to play the latest games at max settings at 1920x1080 and get as close to 30 FPS as possible within the budget.

The trouble is that the website I'm buying from is in Romanian, so using it depends on how patient you are with a few translations.

**Location:** Romania, Bucharest

**Site of choice:** dc-shop.ro ("Componente & Monitoare" from the homepage) / **EDIT:** Also using emag.ro (top-left "Oferta Produse" -> "PC, Periferice & Software")

---Part requirements--------

**Price limit:** 300 RON

**Size:** min 120 GB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Gaming System - CPU \[Romania\]](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/new-gaming-system-cpu-romania)

Comment: Why not use an English site?

Comment: @SeanJ Maybe because shipping?

Answer (score 2):

It will not be possible to build a new gaming system for 300 RON.  You will need at least the following:

1. Motherboard
2. RAM 8GB
3. SSD 120GB +
4. Graphics Card
5. Power supply

I'm assuming you already have a monitor, keyboard and mouse and you will be using a free operating system, e.g. linux.

The cheapest SSD 120GB on dc-shop.ro is:

http://www.dc-shop.ro/ssd_uri/ssd-silicon-power-s60-120gb-sata3-2.5-inch-l/

This costs 199 RON

There is no way you can buy the folowing for 101 RON

Motherboard

RAM 8GB

Graphics Card

Power supply

This site is great when building rigs : pcpartpicker.com

**edit**

It's been suggested that maybe you are just looking for an SSD drive with a budget of 300 RON.

If that is the case then I would recommend spending a bit more and getting a 240GB SSD drive. 353 RON

http://www.dc-shop.ro/ssd_uri/ssd-patriot-blast-series-240gb-sata3-2.5-inch-l/

[image]

http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/6918/patriot-blaze-240gb-ssd-review/index10.html

To me anything less than 200GB in an SSD is a false economoy.  If you absolutely cannot spend more than 300 RON.

http://www.dc-shop.ro/ssd_uri/ssd-corsair-force-series-ls-120gb-sata-3-2.5-inch-mlc-l/

Has the best read/ write speeds. 291 RON

However, when gaming the graphics card will largely determine the frame rate and not the SSD.

Comment: I think you've misread the question - if I think correctly, the price limit stated is the price limit for the SSD alone, not the entire system. That would certainly make more sense. With that in mind, could you make a more concrete *recommendation*?

Comment: @ArtOfCode you could be right, it's not a very well worded question...

Answer (score 1):

A SSD won't matter really for gaming performance, unless your RAM is becoming a limiting factor, or the game is divided into small sections that load in-game(like in Half-Life 2). Most popular today are the 850 Evo series from Samsung, but it seems they're not available. I'd go with Sean's suggestion, but not going for the cheapest 240GB drive, as it'll compromise on other things.

As an independent recommendation, I'd suggest this Sandisk 120GB one:

http://www.dc-shop.ro/ssd_uri/ssd-sandisk-pluus-120gb-sata3-2.5inch-l/

It's a mid-end drive, and Sandisk's drives are good. I have been using their Extreme series of flash drives for a while, and I'm not disappointed.